# Flask WTF upload file error

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I'm getting the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'` when trying to upload a file with Flask.

I'm following the [documentation](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html) but I can't quite get it to work.

```
class SubmitLocations(Form):
    title = TextField("Name Of Location (What do the locals call it)")
    description = TextField("Please describe the location")
    upload = FileField("Please select an image to upload")


@app.route('/add_spot/', methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def add_spot():
    try:
        form = SubmitLocations(request.form)

        if request.method == "POST":
            title = form.title.data
            description = form.description.data
            f = form.upload.data
            filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Here is my HTML form

```
  <form method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/add_spot/">
    <dl>
      {{render_field(form.title)}}
      {{render_field(form.description)}}
      {{render_field(form.upload)}}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Submit></p>
  </form>
```

The page renders just fine, and I can choose a file to upload but when I submit I get the error I mentioned above `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'` I'm wondering if anyone can point me to my error? Maybe I left out a critical piece?

Something to note, if I remove the file upload portion I can submit this form without any error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've submitted the form without a file. You need to validate the form first. If you're relying on having the file, add `FileRequired` to the validators.

```
from flask_wtf.file import FileRequired


class SubmitLocations(Form):
    # ...
    upload = FileField("Please select an image to upload", validators=[FileRequired()])


def add_spot():
    form = SubmitLocations(request.form)

    # changed this line
    if form.validate_on_submit():  
        title = form.title.data
        description = form.description.data
        f = form.upload.data
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Comment: You were correct. I then just had to add 'and validators' to my try statement. Uploads are working, thanks for your help.